# Does MetricBeat/Telegraf supports metrics monitoring from remote?

Tags: elasticsearch, telegraf, metricbeat

I have requirement to install MetricBeat / Telegraf server agents in one server and have to monitor the metrics of other servers remotely. Is this possible with MetricBeat / Telegraf server agents?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the 
[tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour),
 have a look around, and read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) ,
 in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
 and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: That's generally possible in Metricbeat (and I think also telegraf), but perhaps you could give more details on what you are trying to do and why?